# How do you find a vector function that represents the curve of intersection of a sphere and a plane?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Sphere
$$x^2 + (y-\pi)^2 + (z - \frac{1}{18})^2 = (\frac{37}{18})^2$$

Plane
$$x + 6y = 6\pi$$

Solving for $y$ in the plane equation I get:

$$y = \pi - \frac{x}{6}$$

Then plugging $y$ into the sphere equation above I get:

$$x^2 + \frac{x^2}{36} + \left( z - \frac{1}{18} \right)^2 = (\frac{37}{18})^2$$

I solved for $z$ but I get something messy. The answer for this problem is:

$$r(t) =
\left(
   \frac{\sqrt{37}}{3} \cos(t),
  -\frac{\sqrt{37}}{3} \cos(t)+\pi,
   \frac{37}{38} \sin(t)+\frac{1}{18}
\right)$$

How did they jump to trig functions all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

Why trig functions?  When two surfaces intersect in 3-space, they form a curve.  And the best way to represent a curve in 3-space is a parametric equation. The plane and the sphere intersect to form a circle.  And, trig functions are a handy way to paramaterize a circle.

$x^2 + (y-\pi)^2 + (z - \frac{1}{18})^2 = (\frac{37}{18})^2\\
x+6y = 6\pi$

You are in luck the plane intersects the center of the sphere.

otherwise you would have to find the center of the circle.

To do that you would take a vector from the center of the sphere, normal to the plane, until you found the point of intersection.

If you know the center of the circle.  Then you need to find two unit vectors in the plane that are at right angles to one another.  If you find 1, you can use the cross product with the normal vector to find the other.

the parametric equation for the circle will be:
(x,y,z) =center $+ r \cos t \mathbf u+ r \sin t \mathbf v .$

$(0,0,1)$ is a good candidate for $\mathbf u$ and $(6,-1,0)$ is normal to that.

lets unitize that second vector.

$\sqrt{(6^2 + 1^2+0^2)} = \sqrt{37}$

$\mathbf v =(\frac{6}{\sqrt {37}}, -\frac 1{\sqrt{37}}, 0)$

$r = \frac {37}{18}$

$\mathbf x = (0, \pi,\frac 1{18}) + (0,0,\frac {37}{18}) \cos t + (\frac{\sqrt {37}}{3}, \frac {\sqrt{37}}{18}, 0) \sin t$

Comment: You say "parametric equation", but that's not an equation? Also "$\sqrt{37} = (\frac{6}{\sqrt {37}}, -\frac 1{\sqrt{37}}, 0)$" is false.

Comment: @GFauxPas Does this edit address your issues?

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align*}
  \frac{37x^2}{36}+\left( z-\frac{1}{18} \right)^2 &=
  \left( \frac{37}{18} \right)^{2} \\
  \frac{9x^2}{37}+\left( \frac{18z}{37}-\frac{1}{37} \right)^2 &= 1 \\
  \frac{x^2}{\left( \frac{\sqrt{37}}{3} \right)^{2}}+
  \frac{\left( z-\frac{1}{18} \right)^2}
       {\left( \frac{37}{18} \right)^{2}} &= 1 \\
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ z \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{37}}{3} \cos t \\
     \frac{1}{18}+\frac{37}{18} \sin t
  \end{pmatrix} \\[5pt]
  y &= \pi-\frac{x}{6} \\[5pt]
  \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} &=
  \begin{pmatrix}
    \frac{\sqrt{37}}{3} \cos t \\
    \pi-\frac{\sqrt{37}}{18} \cos t \\
    \frac{37}{18} \sin t \end{pmatrix}
\end{align*}

**N.B.**
$$(x,y)=(a\cos t,b\sin t) \implies \frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$